# Laravel 4.2.22 repo cant connect to AWS DB

Tags: mysql, laravel, amazon-rds

I've set up a DB on AWS RDS and when testing our current API against it, I get "Can't connect to MYSQL server...". I can connect to the DB via MYSQL workbench and shell. The API is Laravel 4.2.22 (I know it's old) hosted on an on-prem server via Apache. I duplicated the API, hosting it locally via 'php artisan serve' and was successfully able to hit the DB from that test repo. I need the repo to work on it's current version. I'm not quite sure what to test or where to look. Any direction would be much appreciated.

Error log:

```
stage.ERROR: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '...rds.amazonaws.com' (13)' in /var/www/sites/stage/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:47
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/sites/stage/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php(47): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=hard...', 'user', 'pass', Array)
```

Comment: workbench & shell to connect to RDS works from the on-prem server ?

Comment: check if you have opened the mysql port `3306`  in your inbound rules for your vpc on AWS

Comment: Yes, workbench & shell work from both on and off-prem. I have to specify the port there but Laravel seems to default to port 3306. Even a duplicated version of the repo is able to communicate with the DB.

Comment: @dhof could you please clear the config cache and check if your config works?

Comment: @Tithira Also tried clearing the cache, but the result is the same